# md-button inside ui-gmap-window (angular-google-maps) error

Tags: angularjs, angular-google-maps, angular-material

The Chrome console is throwing this error when I use a md-button in the html inside a google maps infowindow.

```
Error: [ngTransclude:orphan] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ngTransclude/orphan?p0=%3Cbuttonlass%3D%22md-primary%20md-button%20md-default-theme%22%20ng-transclude%3D%22%22%20ng-click%3D%22button1callback()%22%20tabindex%3D%220%22%3E
at Error (native)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js:6:416
at Ja.link (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js:237:351)
at $ (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js:70:46)
at I (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js:59:251)
at g (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js:51:299)
at g (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js:51:316)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.2/angular.min.js:50:414
at WindowChildModel.angular.module.service.buildContent (http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/master/dist/angular-google-maps.js:863:63)
at WindowChildModel.angular.module.service.createWindowOptions (http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/master/dist/angular-google-maps.js:831:29)angular.js:11383 (anonymous function)angular.js:8459 $getangular.js:8127 $angular.js:7637 Iangular.js:6993 gangular.js:6996 gangular.js:6872 (anonymous function)angular-google-maps.js:863 angular.module.service.buildContentangular-google-maps.js:831 angular.module.service.createWindowOptionsangular-google-maps.js:3355 angular.module.factory.WindowChildModel.createGWinangular-google-maps.js:3240 __bindangular-google-maps.js:3285 WindowChildModelangular-google-maps.js:6930 angular.module.factory.Window.initangular-google-maps.js:6915 (anonymous function)angular.js:12984 (anonymous function)angular.js:14200 $get.k.$evalangular.js:14016 $get.k.$digestangular.js:14238 (anonymous function)angular.js:4842 eangular.js:5215 (anonymous function)
```

I'm using the angular-google-maps http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/ library to use google maps with angular. In this plunker you can reproduce the error http://embed.plnkr.co/fWlFjuyuldZj6uITvWH7/preview

Do you have any idea how to fix this?
When I use a native html button it works well, but I need to use angular material.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The markup which you have written inside `<ui-gmap-window>` is getting compiled multiple times. Hence the error.

I have created a directive to not to compile the contents by the controllers scope.

Here is the updated plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/y02RsaWBMuaiwCT0jPua?p=preview